# User Authentication Dialog in TortoiseSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have saved the username and password in user authentication dialog. After some days it shows the dialog for username and password. I didn't clear the cache from SVN. I don't know why its throwing the dialog. any idea?

Comment: Put them again what's the big deal?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Subversion configuration file (on Windows, it's in %APPDATA%\Subversion\config): http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7)/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.servers
Set store-auth-creds on to cache user name and password.